# event.respondWith not work with return a cached response when offline

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am working on an PWA app for my website to cache post request and response a cached response from indexeddb on offline mode. When it's online, all things going on well, but on offline mode, it's net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBdTV.png)

I tried to print response, it's correct. The first request from XHR is correct, but the second request from FETCH is show an net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED error.

my code is like this:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', async (event: any) => {
    const request = event.request as Request
    if (request.method === 'POST' || new RegExp(postRequestMatch).test(request.url)) {
      const table = getPostReqCache()
      event.respondWith(
        fetch(request.clone())
          .then(response => {
            if (response.status > 0 && response.status <= 200) {
              cachePut(request.clone(), response.clone(), table)
            }
            return response
          })
          .catch(async error => {
            const response = await cacheMatch(request.clone(), table)
            return response
          }),
      )
    }
  })
```

Maybe return a response in catch block not work for event.respondWith, I also tried try catch, it's also not work.

Expect the cache return from request could work on offline mode.